# Variable is used before it is declared

Tags: apex, error, compile

I've got this line of code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile('(?:([\\w&&[^_]]+)|.)+');
```

However, I'm getting this error in the Developer Console:

> Variable pattern is used before it is declared

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Apex is case insensitive](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code:_The_Basics#Case_Sensitivity).

Apex is trying to use the variable you are declaring instead of referencing the class. To Apex, `pattern` and `Pattern` are the same thing, and at the moment `pattern` is closest in scope. Try renaming it to `p` or `patternA` or whatever makes most sense for your code.

Comment: Or, if you *must* use the variable name pattern (why, oh, why?!) you can always refer to System.Pattern to avoid confusion: `System.Pattern pattern = System.Pattern.compile(...);` I'd avoid doing this, personally. Things tend to break.